# Why are fields denoted by $\mathbb{K}$?

Tags: notation, terminology

In a lot of papers and books, $\mathbb{K}$ means $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

I know that $\mathbb{R}$ comes from the word "real", and $\mathbb{C}$ from the word "complex". But what about $\mathbb{K}$?

And why is it better to state theorems over $\mathbb{K}$ and not just over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: K usually just refers to the field of scalars, or just any field in general

Comment: Probably from German *Körper*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The letter $\mathbb{K}$ comes from the German word *Körper* (body). In Portuguese, for example, a similar word is used, *corpo*, which also stands for body. People rather state results for $\mathbb{K}$ just because it is more general.

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting, because for any field we use $\mathbb{F}$, but $\mathbb{K}$ is specially for complex or real numbers. But _Körper_ makes sense.

Comment: I don't know if $\mathbb{F}$ is so standard.. here we use $\Bbb K$ in general contexts, not only for $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Comment: I think $\mathbb F$  (or, in traditional typography,  $\mathbf F$) is rather in use for *finite* fields.

Answer (score 4):

The name used in German for “field” is [“Körper”](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_%28Algebra%29).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question as to whether it's better to state a theorem over a general field $\Bbb K$ than over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$: it really depends on the result, and how general it is (that is, for which fields it holds).  For example, the following theorem is true for *any* field, so it's well expressed in terms of the generic $\Bbb K$:

> **Theorem.** Let ${\Bbb K}[x]$ be a polynomial ring over a field ${\Bbb K}$.  Suppose $f\in{\Bbb K}[x]$ has a root $a\in \Bbb K$.  Then $(x-a)$ divides $f$.

However, the following theorem expresses the fact that $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed; it is not true if $\Bbb C$ is replaced by $\Bbb R$.

> **Theorem.** Let $f\in{\Bbb C}[x]$ have degree $n>0$ and leading coefficient $1$.  Then $f$ factors as $f(x) =(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ and this factorization is unique up to permutation of the factors.